# How assign Value to Xpath to find element by WebDriver or WebElement in java code

Tags: java, android, selenium, xpath

Here is my **Java code**

```
List<?> imageList =driver.findElementsByXPath("//*[@class='android.widget.ImageButton' and @index='0']");
```

I want to change class and index to random value.
I've try to set two variable and replace class and index value but it did not work.

```
List<?> imageList =driver.findElementsByXPath("\"//*"+"[@class="+"'"+Itemname+"'"+" "+"and"+" "+"@index="+"'"+Value+"'"+"]\"");
```

The **error** message is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
```

Is any way to help me to solve this problem??
Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
    String ItemName="android.widget.ImageButton";
    String Value="0";
    String str="//*[@class='"+ItemName+"' and @index='"+Value+"']"; //use this str in code

   //or you can directly use like below

   List imageList =driver.findElementsByXPath("//*[@class='"+ItemName+"' and @index='"+Value+"']");
```

Thanks,
Murali

Comment: Thanks you so much Murali, I've try this way and it works.